# How to obtain the feature as in wallet in windows phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I want to obtain the Passcode protection feature in my app as it is in `Wallet App` which is already exist in Windows Phone emulator. After setting the pin and exit from the app. Then again start the app it ask for the Wallet pin. How to obtain that view in my app. My Question is whether it is default library in Windows Phone 8 or we have to built itself? if it is default then what we called it how to do access such thing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This would have to be built by you or from a 3rd party - there is nothing in the SDK that implements the behaviour you are after.